# Regex: Exact number of symbols and lines

Tags: regex

I would like to use regex in Java to substring text.
The string must be max 140 characters in all ( not counting  new line/enter characters) and there might be max 4 lines

I found out how to substring 140 symbols: ^(.|\n|\r){0,140}
My question is how to add limitation for only 4 lines 
and exclude new line/enter characters

Thanks for help!

Comment: "Helping" != "Doing it all for you".

Comment: Is it last line or all lines? Your question is not clear

Comment: 4 lines of 140 chars each?

Comment: @AlexBay There should be 140 characters at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression should do what you are looking for:

```
^([^\r\n]{0,140}(\r?\n|$)){4}
```

**[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/pG6tR7/1)**

Comment: Thanks @AlexBay! It's exactly I was looking for!